# Computing a simple limit of exponentials using Taylor Series expansion

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, taylor-expansion

Suppose I want to show that $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty } \frac{xe^{2x}}{e^{4x}-1} = 0$ by means of Taylor series expansion. Now,

$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty } \frac{xe^{2x}}{e^{4x}-1} = \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty } \frac{x(1+2x + o(x))}{4x+(4x)^2/2 + o(x^2)} = \frac{1+2x + o(x)}{4+8x+ o(x)} $. I am not sure how to proceed after this.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Your $o(x)$'s are not valid for $x \to \infty$. They are for $x \to 0$.

Comment: Divide the numerator and the denominator by $e^{2x}$ and then apply the MacLaurin expansion or just estimate the denominator from below by an appropriate part of the MacLaurin series.